# Mobile HTML5 API integration support

Tags: html, api, mobile

**Would mobile HTML5 support the following, and if not, why?**

```
Device connected to the net
    App loaded
    App calls remote API and responds to request for API credentials
    App receives session token
    App requests data from remote API using session token
    App pushes data to local database and screen
    App closed
Device disconnected from net
    App loaded
    App loads data from local database
    User inputs data which is added to the local database
    App closed
Device connected to net
    App loaded
    App sync's remote/local data
    App closed
Device connected to net
    App closed
    App push notifications enabled in device settings
    Push notification sent to device from remote server
    Native device prompt displayed for push notification
```

Comment: I do not think you can do native push notifications from Safari. I assume you're talking about iPhone, right?

Comment: +1 @Eli: The mobile-web would include, but not be limited to: Safari on iOS, Android Browser, Google Chrome, Amazon Silk, BlackBerry Browser. Nokia Browser, Internet Explorer, Opera Mobile, Opera mini  Firefox, and webOS Browser. That said, I iOS and Android devices hold the majority of the market, though to be honest, I have no idea how to to segment and estimate the mobile-browser market shares, or the support for HTML5 feature sets. That help, or confuse the matter more? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will get you going on the right path? http://mobilehtml5.org/

There's no HTML5 feature called "push notification" nor, as far as I know, any way to create native notifications in iOS or Android from the browser. So right off the bat, that's going to be a tough one.

Comment: +1 @Eli: Thanks, so that means to your knowledge that **all but the set of functionals related to the "push notifications" are possible using HTML5**, right? Ask because even after looking at the chart, it's unclear if that's the case. Again, thanks!

Comment: I can't say for sure. Most of your question is pretty vague. For example, *most* mobile browsers let you access a local database, but there are significant performance and size limitations that may make it impossible to do whatever you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The use of this would be for a demo, and the "push notifications" are in fact not a requirement. I'm just trying to make sure before I head down the rabbit hole, that I should expect to find what I need. Make sense?

Comment: Just to update - as of Dec 2015, Push Notifications are already available on the Web Platform and the adoption is limited, but growing - see https://whatwebcando.today/push-notifications.html